# Calendar meetings using Exchange Web Services

Tags: arrays, powershell, exchangewebservices

[Leading on from the following thread 'time-spent-in-meetings-using-exchange-web-services'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711714/time-spent-in-meetings-using-exchange-web-services)

As well as going by the advised link posted

[EWS-Script-to-Export](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/EWS-Script-to-Export-c76a0ad4)

I'm trying to figure out how to omit certain email domains, however unsure how to do this within an array.

Running the following:

```
$item.RequiredAttendees.Where{$_.address -notlike "*@excludeDomain.com"}
```

will work on it's own.

However within an array it removes everything.

Original code from the script

```
foreach($attendee in $Item.RequiredAttendees){
  $atn = $attendee.Address + "; "  
  $rptObj.Attendees += $atn
  }
```

Example:

```
    foreach($attendee in $Item.RequiredAttendees.Where{$_.address -notlike "*@excludeDomain.com"}){
  $atn = $attendee.Address + "; "  
  $rptObj.Attendees += $atn
  }
```

Would it be better in that case to create a custom object or make the foreach statement into a variable?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

figured it out in the end.

```
foreach($attendee in $Item.RequiredAttendees.Where{$_.Address -notlike 
"*@ExcludeDoman.com" -and 
$_.Address -notlike "*@ExcludeAnotherDoman.com"}){
$atn = $attendee.Address + "; "
$rptObj.Attendees += $atn
}
```